# Where is WinMerge?

Tags: winmerge

Oh no.

http://www.winmerge.org/

and

http://winmerge.org/

and

http://manual.winmerge.org/Command_line.html

are bringing up links on **"how I can get out of debt"**........

:<

Here are some "alternates" that I found:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/winmerge/

https://bitbucket.org/jtuc/winmerge2011/overview

Comment: I was trying to find the documentation to WinMerge, specifically the command line options.  The documentation seems to have vanished.  That's a "real question" to me, but to each his own I guess.

Comment: Here it is https://bitbucket.org/jtuc/winmerge2011/downloads

Comment: Year 2023 Update : https://github.com/WinMerge/winmerge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now access http://sourceforge.net/projects/winmerge/ which is the project website.

https://bitbucket.org/jtuc/winmerge2011/overview is the source repository (as GitHub)

Comment: Does the documentation exist anywhere?  Like "command line" is what started me on this path.  I can't find any documentation under the project website.  But I may be slow.

Comment: It seems no doc is currently available on project website.

Comment: Nooooooooooooooooooooo!  :<

Comment: Upvote for your response.  I don't shoot the messenger!  :>

Comment: I made a whois request : the domain has been created on 04-Mar-2004 06:19:18 UTC. Maybe Winmerge team forgot to renew the domain and will create another one